# Verifying $\int_0^\pi  \sin(x) /2(\sin(x/(2n+1)) \,dx \leq \pi$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, integration

I'm having trouble verifying this inequality.  It goes like this (appears in Giaquinta, Mathematical analysis, linear and metric structures, page 445):
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi} \cfrac{\sin(x)}{\sin\left(\frac{x}{2n+1}\right)} dx \leq\frac{ 2(n+1)\pi}{2n+1} \leq 2\pi
$$
Of course, the last inequality is obvious.  The first one, however, I can't show.  I've tried bounding $\sin(x)$ by $1$, and then calculating the integral with mathematica, but it comes out unbounded.  When I put $n=1,2,3...$ or any finite number in mathematica, the result is numerically true, but I want to show this for any "$n$", and mathematica gives me a very complicated function (depending on $n$) with imaginary units and hypergeometric functions.  I guess I'm missing out a very simple argument here.  Any ideas?

**Edit:** I have edited so that the formula is identical to the one of the book.

Comment: If you just write out function names like that, $\TeX$ interprets them as strings of variable names, which it italicizes. To get the right formatting, you need to use the predefined commands like `\sin` or, if you need a function for which there's no predefined command, `\operatorname{name}`.

Comment: I have reformatted your integrand. Please make sure I've done so correctly.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Thank you both!

Comment: The purported inequality [does not hold](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%28sin%28x%29%2F%282*sin%28x%2F5%29%29%2C{x%2C0%2CPi}%29+%3C+Pi) already for $n=2$. Indeed, $\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin(x)}{2 \sin(x/5)} \mathrm{d} x = \frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{5}{16} \sqrt{50+22\sqrt{5}} \approx 4.68317 > \pi$

Comment: Sasha is right.  My mathematica command had an unfortunate error as well, and the inequality does not hold, so what i wrote in my question is wrong.  I am so sorry.  But if this is wrong i wonder what Giaquinta meant, because... if this does not hold, i have a bigger problem than before.

Comment: The given integral is greater than $n$

$$\begin{equation*}
\int_{0}^{\pi }\frac{\sin x}{2\sin \left(\frac{x}{2n+1}\right)}dx\geq \int_{0}^{\pi }
\frac{\sin x}{\frac{2x}{2n+1}}dx=\frac{1}{2}\left( 2n+1\right) \int_{0}^{\pi
}\frac{\sin x}{x}\geq n,
\end{equation*}$$
because for $0\leq x\leq \pi $
$$\begin{equation*}
\sin \left(\frac{x}{2n+1}\right)\leq \frac{x}{2n+1}.
\end{equation*}$$

Comment: Thanks Americo, I was observing this fact empirically with mathematica.  Nevertheless Siminore found the mistake in the textbook where this whole misunderstanding came from.

Answer (score 3):

Giaquinta and Modica are right, although they are wrong. Let me explain: the book suggests to compute $G_n \left( \frac{2 \pi}{2n+1} \right)$, where
$$
G_n(x) = \int_0^x D_n(t)\, dt
$$
and $D_n$ is the standard Dirichlet kernel. In their computation there is a very stupid mistake: they change variable and they forget to change the differential! Here is a corrected version of their formula on page 445:
$$
\begin{align*}
\|G_n\|_\infty &= G_n \left( \frac{2 \pi}{2n+1} \right) = \int_0^{2\pi/(2n+1)} \frac{\sin (n+1/2)s)}{\sin (s/2)}ds\\
&= \frac{2}{2n+1} \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin t}{\sin \frac{t}{2n+1}}dt \leq \frac{2}{2n+1} \cdot (2n+1)\pi = 2\pi.
\end{align*}
$$
We have used the fact that $t \mapsto \frac{\sin t}{\sin \frac{t}{2n+1}}$ is decreasing, so that it is always less that its limit as $t \to 0^+$.

I hope my answer will be useful.

Comment: I had just realized this error, but was still trying to understand the inequality.  Thank you Siminore, that was really helpfull!!